# How to use "sqldf" in a function

Tags: r, sqldf

I am trying with the below code but getting the error:
I tried with both "sprintf", "fn$sqldf" to select the output.
my function will run two times one with the column "a" and another with column "e".
Please suggest. I got this suggestion from some member and edit the code.`enter code here`

```
db2 = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), 
                 b = c("b","a","c"), 
                 e=  c(4,6,3))

library(sqldf)
       extrct = function(id)
   {
       filedata1 <-  sprintf("select max(%s) as maxid from db2",id)
       filedata3 <- fn$sqldf("select max(id) as maxid from db2")

    }
    extrct(a)
    extrct(e)
```

ERROR:

```
Error in sprintf("select max(%s) as maxid from db2", id) : 
  object 'a' not found
Error in sprintf("select max(%s) as maxid from db2", id) : 
  object 'e' not found
```

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: `filedata <- sqldf(paste0("select name, max(",id,") from income"))`

Comment: That is because you need to pass in the value of the variable id to your sql statement.  You can do it using `sprintf`. Try using the query `sprintf("select  name, max(%s) from income",id) `

Comment: Please provide a complete example including all `library` statements, the values of all inputs, the error message, the expected output and a description in words of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Here's a very similar question that asked for using PostgresSQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316946/call-sql-function-within-r-function and one that asks for multiple queries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636760/wrapping-a-function-around-multiple-sql-queries-in-r/19637101#19637101 and this one looks pretty much like an answer to an exact duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188139/function-create-with-sqldf-in-r/32189346?s=5|31.9807#32189346

Answer (score 2):

**1)** In the absence of a complete example in the question maybe you want to find the row in `income` corresponding to a specific id -- below we find the row in `income` having `id` equal to 3.

```
library(sqldf)

income <- data.frame(name = letters, id = 1:26) # test data

newvalue <- function(income, id) {
  fn$sqldf("select * from income where id = $id")
}

newvalue(income, 3)
##   name id
## 1    c  3
```

**2)** or using base R:

```
newvalue2 <- function(income, id) income[income$id == id, ]
newvalue2(income, 3)
##   name id
## 3    c  3
```

Comment: @GGrothendieckThis is interesting. I did not know you could use a variable substitution/evaluation with `fn$sqldf` . Apparently sqldf uses `gsubfn` package to do this. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/README.html . Will explore it further. Thanks for sharing this code